# jQueryUI auto-complete IE5

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, internet-explorer-5

Since my project need to use autocomplete via javascript for TextBox.

I would like to know there are any version of jQueryUI has autocomplete function for IE5?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using jQueryUI version 1.8